# Where i can store jar file for connecting database with java

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I am new to java,

I have downloaded jar file, and i have installed oracle 11g express edition.

And i am using eclipse IDE. I want to learn connecting database with java.

May i know, in which location i have to store downloaded jar file and what is the java code for connecting database and how to create data in oracle 11g express edition?

```
public class Strings {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = "Jane";
        String name2 = name.replace('J', 'K');
        String name3 = name2.replace('n', 't');

        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(name3);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Jane");
        System.out.println(sb);

        sb.setCharAt(0, 'K');
        sb.setCharAt(2, 't');

        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

May i know how can i fix this?

Can anybody guide me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use some OR/M framework, but if you are new in java you can JDBC firstly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you have to create JDBC connection with Oracle database using `Connection` class.

> ```
> Connection connection = null;  
> connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:dbname",
> ```
>
> "username",   "password");

2. You have to put your `jar` file in project `lib` folder and then configure it in classpath.
3. Create `Table` in your database.
4. Then you can do your `DML` operation on database.

[Refer this link for more details](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm)

Comment: where i can find lib folder? and where i can create table? I mean have to type query in cmd? Thanks

Comment: If you are creating web project it present in your project or if you are not creating web project then create one folder with name lib in your project.

Comment: In eclipse i go to file-->new-->java project-->i put name called as oracle.. thats it... so i checked oracle folder in my workspace.. i didn't found lib folder.. what to do?

Comment: Now you can create `lib` folder inside this project and put your `jar` in this folder, then configure this jar in eclipse classpath. (It's not necessary to create lib folder)

Comment: Once you configure jar file in class path run your application, I have edited my answer and provided one link refer that link for database connection and all.

Comment: may i know, how to configure the classpath

Comment: where i can add your above code.. I am super newer.. so you have to help me please..

Comment: We understand you are a newbie in java world and probably in It world ... follow this simple advice: first read the documentation and then ask your question.